# React JS - Multi level dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, multi-level

I have this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/89fmj?file=/src/MultiMenus.js). My question is simple: how can I have only one submenu opened at a time?

eg: When the "menu 3" is opened I want "menu 2" to be closed..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an array for `activeMenus` state, use a single value, which can be `null` if no menus are open. (And change the name to `activeMenu`.)

In `handleArrowClick`, set `activeMenu` to `null` if it's already `menuName`, or `menuName` otherwise.

`setActiveMenu(activeMenu === menuName ? null : menuName)`

When rendering `SubMenu`, `toggle={activeMenu === menuName}`

Comment: almost there, but what about "sub menus" ? those are not working anymore

Comment: I realised you have variable scope problems. You need to move all the subcomponent definitions out of the MultiMenus component. Then the event handlers for each component needs to go with its component. If you do that you'll see where you were reading one component's variables inside another, and you'll be able to fix it. Let me know how you get on! And if this helped you, please upvote and accept the answer